# Continue processing when an Exception occurs

Tags: java

I have the below code that basically reads a bunch of JSON strings, and converts them to a java object. My problem is if at any point, the transformation fails for any of the JSON strings, it doesn't process the others strings. What I need is -

1. Find the string for which the error occured.
2. In the exception block do something to continue processing.

Here is my code to convert from JSON to Java.

```
public static <T> T convertToObject(String jsonString,Class<T> classType){
    T obj = null;
    try {
        obj = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to convert to DTO :" + e.getMessage(), e);
    } 
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You are catching the exception and then throwing a new one for the message "unable to convert..."... so where are you catching that second exception?

Comment: Same question as above: Show the code calling your function. You will have to modify that regardless of which type of exception you throw.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a custom deserializer. Standard ObjectMapper will do all or nothing. Read more about creating a custom deserializer for Jackson ObjectMapper here:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: +1, but I suspect this is going to take quite some piece of work to implement.